# Is it possible to create bottom navigation bar in a stack flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to add a bottom navigation bar for my code. but don't know where to add it properly. is it possible to add it in a stack? if not how do I add a navigation bar to my code without errors? can someone please suggest to me what to do about this? here's my home.dart and bottom navigation bar code I hope to add.

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();}

class _HomePageState extends State <HomePage>{
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffEDEFF4),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, left: 20, right: 20),
        child: ListView (
          children: [
            buildSearchInput(),
            Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 45, 10, 0),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          color: Color(0xffCAEC93),
                        ),
                        height: 137,
                        width: 327,
                        child: Column(
                          children: const [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 100, 40),
                              child: Text(
                                "Banana",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily:'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                        )
                ),

                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/banana.png"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),


            Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 45, 10, 0),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          color: Color(0xffCAEC93),
                        ),
                        height: 137,
                        width: 327,
                        child: Column(
                          children: const [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 100, 40),
                              child: Text(
                                "Tangerine",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily:'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    )
                ),

                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/orange.png"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),


            Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 45, 10, 0),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          color: Color(0xffCAEC93),
                        ),
                        height: 137,
                        width: 327,
                        child: Column(
                          children: const [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 40, 100, 40),
                              child: Text(
                                "Kiwi",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily:'Roboto',
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    )
                ),

                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(200, 0, 10, 0),
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/images/kiwi.png"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),





          ],

        ),
      ),
      );

  }


  Widget buildSearchInput() => Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14)),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(
            Icons.search,
            size: 30,
            color: Colors.grey.shade300,
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

  Widget buildCard()=> Container (
    height: 23,
    width: 90,
    color: Color(0xffE6E848),


  );
}
```

my code for bottom navigation bar

```
 Stack(
              children: [
                bottomNaavigationBar:BottomNaavigationBar(
                  items:[
                    BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon:Icon(Icons.Icons.home),
                      backgroundColor:Colors.blue,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon:Icon(Icons.Icons.Icons.favorite),
        label:'Feed'
        backgroundColor:Colors.blue,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon:Icon(Icons.Icons.chat),
        label:'Chat'
        backgroundColor:Colors.blue,
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon:Icon(Icons.Icons.person),
        label:'Profile'
        backgroundColor:Colors.blue,
      ),

                    ),
                  ],

                ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it in Scaffold, sure if you want.
Here is BottomNavBar example with PageView.

Let's define a pageController and currentTab variable for PageView inside our class,

```
    PageController _pageController = PageController();
    int _currentTab = 0;
```

Then we can initialize our controller for initial page.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _currentTab);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Then here our view codes.

```
Scaffold(
        drawer: const CustomDrawerWidget(),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          shape: const CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: _currentTab,
            iconSize: 24,
            selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: _items,
            onTap: (index) {
              setState(() {
                _pageController.jumpToPage(index);

        
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
        body: PageView(
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          pageSnapping: true,
          controller: _pageController,
          children: _pages,
          onPageChanged: (page) {
            setState(() {
              _currentTab = page;
            });
          },
        ),

      
      );
```

BottomNavigationBar items:

```
const _items = [
  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Feed"),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.people), label: "Chat"),
  BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: "Profile"),
];
```

Here is page list:

```
    const _pages= [
  FeedPage(),
  ChatPage(),
  ProfilePage(),
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scaffold` has a property `bottomNavigationBar`

Use it like so:

```
Scaffold(
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
   items: [],
 ),
 ...
)
```